# How do I make the system function call work?

Tags: c, shutdown, keil, 8051

I want to shutdown the computer using an 8051 on the press of a button. Everything including the circuit is working fine except the call to the system function to initiate shutdown. This is because the stdlib.h that comes with Keil C51 does not include this function.

I have tried replacing stdlib.h with the one from MinGW and also from this(they have the system function): https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/stdlib.h.html
Both times compilation failed because these files generate errors(too many to fix). Then I declared my own function(see below) which makes the compilation successful but does not work, i.e., does not shutdown.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <reg51.h>

void Delay(void){
    int j;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        for(j=0;j<10000;j++){}
    }
}

extern int system (const char *__command);

void main(){
    P1=0xFF;
    P2=0x00;
    while(1){
        P2=~P1;
        system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s");
        Delay();
    }
}
```

When a button is pressed, the computer should shut down. However, either compilation fails or the user-defined function does nothing.

Comment: Are you really running Windows on the embedded system? I find that highly unlikely. Read the documentation for the 8051, it should tell you how to reset it *without* having to use any kind of `system` function. There should probably be thousands if not millions of documentation, tutorials and examples all over the Internet (since 8051 seems to be a very popular base for schools).

Comment: You have a 8051 microcontroller? And you want to shutdown your computer from the 8051 microncontroller? How is the 8051 connected to your computer? You do understand the `system` command runs on 8051 microntroller, not on you computer, right?

Comment: You need solution to windows, linux or both? On linux works `FILE* c = popen("command", "r");` and read out like from file.

Comment: Of course you can't use Windows functions on the 8051. The way to shut down a computer is to remove the power, and the way to do that programmatically is to have a latching power switch which can be turned off by software. For example, the power button on my PC isn't the *actual* power switch: that is a relay. What you can do is to perform a [software reset of the 8051](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/762.htm).